# [unity 2d]zoom in and out on the camera when …Can we set a different zoom level for each of the backgrounds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, camera, zooming

I am making a side scrolling game.
What I want is that the layers distant view, middle distance view, near distance view zoom in and out at different ratios.
How do you do that?
[image]

Comment: Well, you didn't explain how the zooming work soo it is impossible to answer. Is it some code you made? you might share it. Also are you using an orthographic camera?

Comment: i’m sorry. i’m not good at english.
I want to express perspective.
I want to a little  zoom out  distant background layer.
i want to  zoom out a lot  close background layer.
In my game the sky layer zoom out a lot.
I want to express it like a Tiny Wings game.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that if you're using an `orthographic` camera, the depth (i.e. `transform.position.z`) is used to decide which objects are rendered on top of others.

Any effect associated with perspective (i.e.: scaling) is lost.

So, in order to do what you want to do, a quick way is to group your objects based on distance (far, middle, near) and scale them accordingly via code (changing their `transform.localScale` X and Y values). Of course the objects on the far distance will change their `localScale` less than the middle, and the middle will change less than the near.